# What is the max value of a CHAR?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering what the max char value is in sql? I noticed in C# this `\uFFFF`, but when I use that value to compare a string SQL renders it as an empty string I think.

The table is in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a deep misconception of *what is ascii*...

ASCII is a 7bit code (0 to 127) where the characters are fix

the 8th bit offers this range a second time (128 to 255). In this area the characters are depending on codepages and collations.

Thinking of `CHAR` as a `BYTE` (8 bit in memory) is misleading...

Try this, both return a captial `A`

```
SELECT CHAR(65) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
SELECT CHAR(65) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
```

The code 255 renders with `Latin1_General_CI_AS` as `ÿ`, with the arabic collation there seems to be no printable character, hence the question mark.

```
SELECT CHAR(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
SELECT CHAR(255) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
```

So in short: *SQL renders it as an empty string* is not true. This is depending on your settings

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) as it clearly says

> **char [ ( n ) ]**
>
> Fixed-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the
>   string length and must be a value from 1 through **8,000**. The storage
>   size is n bytes. The ISO synonym for char is character.

Comment: OP is referring to the max byte value of a single character, not the max number of characters in a field.

Comment: @Anonymous didn't OP said *what the max char value is in sql?*

Comment: @Rahul combined with the remark about C#, I interpret that "max char value" as "what is the range of values that can be stored in a single char" (or a char(1) field)

Answer (score 0):

Numerically, the answer is 255. CHAR has a *potential* range of 0 to 255. It is an 8-bit code unit for the character encoding configured for the field (which it might inherit from the table or database).

Whether 255 is a valid code unit and is a complete codepoint, and which character it represents, and its sort order (is that what you meant by max?), depends on the collation. (A collation specifies a character encoding and sort order.)

---

Oh, if you are going to compare SQL datatypes to others, NVARCHAR and C#'s char and .NET's Char all use UTF-16 as the character encoding.